# How to determine whether UI initiated the SaveAs operation?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to design my Excel tool so that saving can only be initiated using a particular Macro-assigned button. The button will trigger an automated 'SaveAs' operation create a new file with an informative filename.

I'm running into a roadblock when trying to disable the ordinary Save button / command. The following code has the intended effect only if the Save As operation is initiated via the UI...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not SaveAsUI Then
   MsgBox "Use the save button on the homepage!"
   Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

In other words, when my macro runs `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=xxx` I create a sort of paradoxical loop where the `.SaveAs` method triggers my BeforeSave event.

Does anyone know of a work-around? Some sort of flag that can inform my BeforeSave event that the Macro is initiating the Save, rather than the user?

Comment: Perhaps just disable events before the `SaveAs` call and then re-enable?

Comment: This is a good thought but then the saved copy will also have disabled events I believe.

Comment: Set a global flag and then check that in `Workbook_BeforeSave`

Comment: Are you sure that global variables can be accessed by an event in ThisWorkbook? This isn't working for me when I do ```Global TrueSave As Integer``` in the module, set it in the Sub, then put ```If TrueSave = vbYes Then Else: Cancel = True``` in the BeforeSave event. Maybe because the event is in a Private Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Tim's idea, in a standard module:

```
Public IPushedTheButton As Boolean

Sub ButtonCode()
    IPushedTheButton = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

where `ButtonCode` is assigned to the Button.

And the event code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If IPushedTheButton Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Please push the button"
End Sub
```

So if the Button is pushed, the event code gracefully exits and allows the `Save` to proceed.

*(both the button code and the event code can "see" the Boolean flag)*

Comment: This works! In my comment above I was having issues because I had disabled events...